# Have the child iframe reference itself, not the parent iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

What I have is a nested Iframe like this

```
<iframe id="is Static">
   stuff
  <iframe id="Is Dynmic>
     <html>...</html>
     <body id="This is thebody"> other stuff </body>
```

and I have this bit of code that listen to on the mouse up event for the body, use for detecting when text is selected. The way I am binding the event listener is like this

```
 $(window).load(function() {
        var listOfEditor = editorIds.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < listOfEditor.length; i++) {
            var currentFrame = $("#" + listOfEditor[i] + "_ifr");              
            if (currentFrame.exists()) {                 
                currentFrame.contents().find("body").each(function () {                            
                        $(this).on("mouseup", function () {
                           console.log(window.frameElement.contentWindow.getSelection());
                            console.log(window.frames);
                            console.log(window.parent);
                            console.log($(this).parent("iframe");
                        });
                    }
                );
            }               
        };
```

As you can see from above I have a list of Id. The Id name correspond to various iframes on the page, and using that list I find the body of each iframe and bind the event listener to get the selected text depedning which iframe has the selected text. The problem that I am having is that using the `window` object get's me the parent iframe with the static name, but what I want is the reference to the inner iframe that contains the body element. The complete code would look like this

```
<iframe id="is Static">      
<script>
 $(window).load(function() {
        var listOfEditor = editorIds.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < listOfEditor.length; i++) {
            var currentFrame = $("#" + listOfEditor[i] + "_ifr");              
            if (currentFrame.exists()) {                 
                currentFrame.contents().find("body").each(function () {                            
                        $(this).on("mouseup", function () {
                           console.log(window.frameElement.contentWindow.getSelection());
                            console.log(window.frames);
                            console.log(window.parent);
                            console.log($(this).parent("iframe");
                        });
                    }
                );
            }               
        };
</script>
stuff
  <iframe id="Is Dynmic>
     <html>...</html>
     <body id="This is thebody"> other stuff </body>
```

where the `$(window).load` is executed from the parent Iframe level. I have seen various questions, but they are about accessing the parent iframe from within the child iframe, or accessing the elements inside the child iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Since I have the pointer to body, I can use the [ownerDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.ownerDocument) property to get the parent docuemnt.